# Google Chrome won't let me onto particular website

Tags: google-chrome

Not technically about programming, so feel free to delete.

Otherwise...

Since randomly last night every time I try to visit www.freehostia.com my browser tries and fails to connect. I've tried various response sites which tell me it's still up. Any idea what the problem could be? I'm using Chrome 5.0 but I'm experiencing the same problem in Safari 5.0 and Firefox 3.6.8. So far this is the only site I'm having the problem with.

Answer (score 0):

Go down the line:

- Since it's a problem between browsers, it's certainly not a cookie. So that's not it.
- It could be a DNS cache thing or an IP/DHCP thing. Try rebooting your computer and seeing if that fixes anything.
- If not, it may also be a network or ISP thing. Go to the library and see if it's working there.
- If none of those work, try livebooting an Ubuntu install disc to see if it's an OS thing.
- Maybe, if you're desperate, install Opera and see if it works there.

Comment: Might wanna add http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ onto that list. Kind of like going to the library, without the going or the library. :p

Comment: thanks for your replies.
updates:
- doesn't work in opera
- downforeveryone says it's up: that's what i meant by the rather vague term "response site".
- i can get through if i use a proxy

Comment: If you can use a proxy, it's either being blocked or something's wrong with your DNS.
Try running `ping freehostia.com` from the commandline and post the results here.

Comment: Ping has started ...

PING www.freehostia.com (66.40.66.145): 56 data bytes

--- www.freehostia.com ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

Comment: I got the same IP address when I pinged them, so it's definitely not a DNS problem.  
Now, try running `tracert freehostia.com` and posting the results.

Comment: traceroute to www.freehostia.com (66.40.66.145), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  O2WirelessBox (192.168.1.254)  18.547 ms  96.064 ms  100.313 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * *
 *
 4  linx-gw1.peer1.net (195.66.224.156)  22.497 ms  21.426 ms  20.884 ms
 5  216.187.115.33 (216.187.115.33)  113.273 ms  113.355 ms  113.088 ms
 6  10ge.xe-1-0-0.chi-eqx-dis-1.peer1.net (216.187.114.161)  135.153 ms  142.113 ms  134.036 ms
 7  oc48.so-3-1-0.sea-coloc-dis-1.peer1.net (216.187.89.129)  184.207 ms  185.467 ms  184.658 ms
 8  10ge.ten1-2.sj-mkp16-dis-1.peer1.net (216.187.88.202)  202.187 ms  202.626 ms  201.885 ms

Comment: 9  paix-2-pos2-0.maxim.net (216.187.88.250)  204.006 ms  203.299 ms  204.085 ms
10  VLAN5.FMT6509-1.maxim.net (66.40.24.70)  204.769 ms  202.814 ms  207.901 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *

just continues like this, it's currently on 33.

Comment: Well, peer1 is a hosting service, but maxim.net seems out of place. Whatever that is is probably what's holding you down.